# Remove Desktop from Home Folder

Tags: gnome, home-directory

I'm using Gnome Shell and have the desktop turned off. So there are no icons and it's not clickable except for the right click which offers to change my wallpaper. There's still a folder for the desktop in my home folder which is now serving no purpose. How can I get rid of it?

I tried changing `~/config/user-dirs.dir` and `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` to not include the desktop but the folder remains there after a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the changes I made to `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` worked. It didn't remove the folder nor did it give me the option to delete it with a right click, but I was able to drag the Desktop folder into another and there I was able to delete it.

Comment: What changes did you made ? because I am having the same problem. Thanks